# PostgreSQL column type conversion form bigint to bigserial with Liquibase changeset

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, liquibase

When i want modify the id column type from bigint to bigserial,
there is an error:
"Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: type "bigserial" does not exist"

My code:

```
<changeSet id="change_id_type_to_bigserial" >
    <dropSequence sequenceName="position_data_id_seq"/>
    <modifyDataType columnName="id" newDataType="BIGSERIAL" tableName="position_data"/>
</changeSet>
```

What is  wrong?

//
it is so wird for me, because this snippet of an other part of code is working:

```
<column name="id" type="BIGSERIAL">
            <constraints primaryKey="true"/>
</column>
```

//

Comment: `serial` and `bigserial` isn't a "data type". It's just [a shortcut](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) for a default value taken from a sequence which gets "expanded" during a create table, but can't be used in an ALTER TABLE. If you already have a sequence and the column already uses that sequence as the default value, then you effectively **have**  a "serial" column.

Comment: thanks for your answer